# selenium can't open url with firefox

Tags: python, selenium

Hello I try to start small code on python with selenium

```
options = Options()
options.binary = which("firefox")
options.headless = True
_logger.info('Start driver, {}'.format(which("firefox")))
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service_log_path='/opt/selenium/selenium.log', options=options)
_logger.info('Getting URL. {}'.format(url))
driver.get(url)
```

I start it in docker and when it try to get url i receive this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette
```

in selenium log i  see this information

```
1584599749872   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileV7HwxB"
*** You are running in headless mode.
1584599750476   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons
1584599750476   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: resource://pdf.js/
1584599750476   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: about:reader*
1584599752609   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 40068
1584599752687   Marionette      WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Exiting due to channel error.
[Child 3352, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error (3): Connection reset by peer: file /builds/worker/workspace/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 357
Exiting due to channel error.
[GFX1-]: Receive IPC close with reason=AbnormalShutdown
[Child 3378, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error (50): Connection reset by peer: file /builds/worker/workspace/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 357
[Child 3378, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /builds/worker/workspace/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 726
Exiting due to channel error.
```

my geckodriver version is 0.26
python selenium==3.141.0
firefox --version Mozilla Firefox 67.0.4

docker starts with shm-size: 2gb

Comment: use chrome browser instance, firefox has an issue of crashing browsers. check https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1560

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The headless modification didn't help.
I solved this problem by installing **Xlib** and using **PyVirtualDisplay**